# programmatically added tablview's scroll disabled

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, messageui

I added tableview to scrollview programmatically but it is not scrolling. While i tried the same using XIB. but it is working fine.

here is my code

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(30, 30.0f, 900, 300.0f);

```
eappTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]  style:UITableViewStylePlain];

eappTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

eappTable.delegate = self;

eappTable.dataSource = self;

eappTable.scrollEnabled = YES;

eappTable.scrollsToTop = YES;
```

[eappTable reloadData];

```
[scrollView addSubview:eappTable];
```

Comment: try explicitly enabling scroll

Comment: have you given the content size of scrollview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eappTable = [[UITableView alloc] nitWithFrame:YourSize style:Table_Style]];
eappTable.delegate = self;
eappTable.dataSource = self;
eappTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
[scrollView addSubview:eappTable];
```

And set `self.scrollView.contentSize`

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the Content Size of ScrollView.

Hope it Helps !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to enable bouncing (because if all cells size are smaller than the uitableview size it self, it won't scroll if bounce is set to NO)  :

eappTable.bounces = YES;

Answer (score 0):

```
[eappTable  setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 680)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you are looking for. But I would like to mention one point : 
**Never add tableview as the subview of your scrollview**.

> Important: You should not embed `UIWebView` or `UITableView` objects
>   in `UIScrollView` objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can
>   result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and
>   wrongly handled.

- From [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)